# ASP.NET RadioButton | Change HTML Generated

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, material-design

I'm basically using asp.net controls (runat="server") and I have this code:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="RadioButtonRating" class="col-md-4 control-label">Select</label>
<div class="col-md-8">
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonRating" runat="server"
    RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table" AppendDataBoundItems="true" class="">
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</div>
```

I'm inserting the radio button items dynamically by using an SQL Adapter.

My main issue is that I want to implement directly bootstrap for material design, and the code must be written differently than the code that asp.net is generated.

I want to have this:

```
<div class="radio radio-primary">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked="">
        Option one is this
      </label>
</div>
```

Code is generated like:

```
<input id="MainContent_RadioButtonRating_2" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$RadioButtonRating" value="3">
<label for="MainContent_RadioButtonRating_2">3</label>
```

I guess my main issue is to remove the "for=" from the label, and to put input between the label tags.

I guess I have two options. By stick with the asp.net radio control and dynamically change this to fit (any ideas how?). Or by taking out the asp.net radio button control (if I do this, can I still in the same form use other asp.net controls? Can I still manipulate the radio button in the code side?

Comment: You may try to create a Server Control.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends if you need access to the controls properties on the sevrer side afterwards... but you could create this as a literalControl in the code behind and add add it to the controls collection of the parent element.

Here's a very crude example of adding a div panel to form...

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LiteralControl litCon = new LiteralControl("<div>Hello</div>");
        form1.Controls.Add(litCon);
    }
```

Although using this, you will not have direct access to the control properties server side.